# Phoenix controller test case loses current_user

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I'm facing the problem where all tests in which I need to assert more than one thing with a logged in user, it seems that it loses the saved session.

I have a setup code which assigns a fixture user before each test:

```
setup %{conn: conn} = config do
  if username = config[:login_as] do
    user = insert_user(username: username)
    conn = assign(conn, :current_user, user)
    {:ok, conn: conn, user: user}
  else
    :ok
  end
end
```

All my tests which happen in the logged-in area take the tag `login_as: "username"`.

```
@tag login_as: "max"
test "redirects to show when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = post conn, debit_event_path(conn, :create), debit_event: @create_attrs

  assert %{id: id} = redirected_params(conn)
  assert redirected_to(conn) == debit_event_path(conn, :show, id) #1

  conn = get conn, debit_event_path(conn, :show, id) 
  assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Show Debit event" #2
end
```

The first assertion *(#1 comment in code)* always works, but for some reason, the second assertion *(#2 comment in code)* fails and it behaves as if my user was logged out. It happens in all cases where I need to persist the user between requests.

Is there a correct approach to have this data persisted across tests requests as it was a browser request?

Comment: The lines in the tests override the initially set up `conn`, thus the `conn = post conn...` overrides the one assigned in `test "...", %{conn: conn}`, and later used in `conn = get conn...`. You could either separate the cases to separate tests, to try renaming the `conn` that is _modified by requests_ eg: `resp_conn = post conn...` and then `assert redirected_to(resp_conn) == ...`. The same thing for `resp_conn = get conn`, so the original `conn` is used to initiate the request/response, but the effect would be assigned to a fresh variable and not re-used for next request. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue, Pawel's comments helped me out... so with your example above, based on Pawel's response you could do something like the below and you should be good.

```
  @tag login_as: "max"
  test "redirects to show when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    create_conn = post conn, debit_event_path(conn, :create), debit_event: @create_attrs

    assert %{id: id} = redirected_params(create_conn)
    assert redirected_to(create_conn) == debit_event_path(create_conn, :show, id) #1

    show_conn = get conn, debit_event_path(conn, :show, id)
    assert html_response(show_conn, 200) =~ "Show Debit event" #2
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix emulates browser cookies to using [Recycling](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.2/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#module-recycling)

> ## Recycling
>
> Browsers implement a storage by using cookies. When a cookie is set in
>   the response, the browser stores it and sends it in the next request.
>
> To emulate this behaviour, this module provides the idea of recycling.
>   The
>   [recycle/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.2/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#recycle/1)
>   function receives a connection and returns a new connection, similar
>   to the one returned by conn/0 with all the response cookies from the
>   previous connection defined as request headers. This is useful when
>   testing multiple routes that require cookies or session to work.

So if you'd like to preserve the user between requests in tests, you'd need to store a `user_id` in the session.